# How can I assign value into difference parameter from the same time in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I assign value into difference parameter from the same time in SQL Server?

Example:

I have table that has columns age, name, address. How can I assign those values into the declared parameters `@age int`, `@name varchar(max)` and `@address varchar(max)`?

I wrote the following code, but it's not working

```
set @age = age,  
set @name = name, 
set @address = address 
from [dbo].[test]
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Don't make us guess.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which DMBS you are using, but in mysql you can do this:

```
select @name := name, @age := age from dbo.test
```

Of course it will only store the field of the last row matched, so you will need to use an appropriate where clause to choose the row you are interested in.

You can also use the set command, but you will need a separate query for each field you want set:

```
set @name = (select name from dbo.test limit 1)
set @age = (select age from dbo.test limit 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT @age = age,@name = name,@address = address FROM [dbo].[test]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT @age = age,
       @name = name,
       @address = address 
FROM dbo.test 
WHERE primarykey = somevalue
```